# how to connect blackberry10 simulator to momentics ide?

Tags: blackberry-simulator

I have momentics ide and simulator installed on system.When I connect simulator to ide, it asks for an ip address of the simulator.how to know that ip address?

Answer (score 0):

Provided you have already installed VMWare Player and have the simulator up and running, the simulator IP is located at the bottom left of the vmware player window.

[image]